# CSS: @import: why must it come first?

Tags: css, import

The book "CSS and Documents" by O'Reilly states:

"CSS requires the @import directive to come before any other rules in a style sheet."

I wonder, why was CSS designed in this way? After all, if the import came after
some other palin text CSS rules then why couldn't it simply be set to override
them or extend them in the middle of the document style rules?

Thanks.

Comment: “Why” questions usually call for opinions, speculations, extended discussion, etc. SO is generally for real problems that you are facing in practice, rather than “I’d just like to know” things.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela "I'd just like to know" things are the most important real problems for every human being which cares about understanding this world. And: Understanding the "why" in a design offloads the need to memorize things. In this particular case I suggest: Mindlessness of the designers. And: I hope to be corrected.

Answer (score 1):

As per the official [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#at-import):

> The '@import' rule allows users to import style rules from other style sheets. In CSS 2.1, any @import rules must precede all other rules (except the @charset rule, if present).

It must be placed there, before the other CSS rules, or else it won't work at all.An `@import` rule that follows one or more rule sets will be ignored.

Comment: This does not answer the original question, it merely repeats it. That's why I downvoted.